# Should i use Growl on a mac app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications, growl

I design an app for mac (new in cocoa) and i need to use a notification on monitor. I was going to implement growl. But i see that growl now is not free at App Store. So i wondered if it will still be the default notification manager on macs.

So do you think that i should use Growl for my screen notifications? If not any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not free, however you can download a standalone Growl library that allows your app to show Growl notifications without actually having to install Growl on the user's Mac.

Please refer to Growl's website for more info.

With that said, yes, using growl is recommended due to the familiarity it enjoys. If you are gonna support Mac OS X 10.8+, however, I'd say just use the new Notification Center.

Comment: Conversely, if you're going to support Lion, using the Growl framework enables you to provide any notifications at all on those systems. Notification Center is only available on Mountain Lion and later.